# PHP/Wordpress Check to see if post is in category, and then display icon. Partially Working

Tags: php, wordpress, icons, categories

http://104.152.110.248/~baron/category/recipes/ - The Website i'm working on

So what i'm doing is having it so that when the post (recipie) is in a certain category, I want the corresponding icon to appear next to the title of the post.
For instance, the crab cakes are in the fish category, so it should display only the fish icon next to the title. And the Filet Mingion is only in the beef category, so it should only display the cow icon.

The problem I have is that if there are ANY posts with the assigned category of beef, it displays a beef icon for ALL posts. While I want it only to display for the post that has the beef category assigned to it.

This is the current code I'm using in order to do this.

```
    <?php 
    if ($all_the_tags);
    $all_the_tags = get_categories();
    foreach($all_the_tags as $this_tag) {
        if ($this_tag->name == "Spicy" ) {
    ?>
        <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Chili Pepper Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if ($this_tag->name == "Chicken" ) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Chicken Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if ($this_tag->name == "Vegetables" ) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Tomato Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if ($this_tag->name == "Fish" ) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Fish Food Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if ($this_tag->name == "Pork" ) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Pig.png">

    <?php   } else if ($this_tag->name == "Beef" ) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Cow Filled.png">

    <?php   } else {    
            // it's neither, do nothing
    ?>
            <!-- not tagged as one or the other -->
    <?
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replace your code with below code:

```
<?php 
        if (has_category("Spicy",get_the_id())) {
    ?>
        <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Chili Pepper Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if (has_category("Chicken",get_the_id())) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Chicken Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if (has_category("Vegetables",get_the_id())) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Tomato Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if (has_category("Fish",get_the_id())) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Fish Food Filled.png">

    <?php   } else if (has_category("Pork",get_the_id())) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Pig.png">

    <?php   } else if (has_category("Beef",get_the_id())) { ?>

                <img class="icons" src="http://104.152.110.248/~baron/wp-content/themes/Baron/img/icons/Cow Filled.png">

    <?php   } else {    
            // it's neither, do nothing
    ?>
            <!-- not tagged as one or the other -->
    <?
    }
?>
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/